# Word 365 2016 - Add custom button to Home tab

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, office365, ribbon

I am trying to add a custom button to the home tab in MS Word (365/2016) but having no luck. Nothing happens, no custom button appears. My XML as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabHome">
        <group id="CustomGroup1" label="my Group" insertAfterIdMso="GroupEditing">
          <button id="Button1" label="insert custom footnote" size="large" imageMso="FootnoteInsert" onAction="RibbonControl.myMacro"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CustomUI xml has an error, so it will not load. Word will silently block the xml unless you turn on the option to show errors.

- In Word go to File | Options | Advanced | General and ensure that
  "Show add-in user interface errors" is checked.

The line with the error:

```
<group id="CustomGroup1" label="my Group" insertAfterIdMso="GroupEditing">
```

`insertAfterIdMso` is invalid. It should be `insertAfterMso`, making the corrected line:

```
<group id="CustomGroup1" label="my Group" insertAfterMso="GroupEditing">
```

You can avoid errors in your xml by using a tool such as the [Office RibbonX Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor) which will enable you to validate the xml.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue. I am using the Ribbon X editor, for some reason it validated the xml fine even though insertAfterIdMso was present, not sure why it did that though